# Merging two files in awk

Tags: awk

I have a two files. File 1 looks like this:

`a  1 
 b  6
 c  8`

The second file is:

`a  2
b  4.5
c  3.8`

I want to merge file 1 and file 2 in a way that always outputs:

`a  1
a  2 
b  6
b  4.5
c  8
c 3.8`

Comment: `awk '{print; if(getline < "file2") print}' file1` from [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011814/how-to-interleave-lines-from-two-text-files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011814/how-to-interleave-lines-from-two-text-files)

Answer (score 0):

According to [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30137092/309308), you can do:

```
awk '{print; if(getline < "file2") print}' file1
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you want them to be interleaved, you could also try `cat file1.txt file2.txt | sort > files.txt`